# Woocommerce checkout ajax load in popup

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to design a popup with multi-step checkout. I already created a cart and login module from scratch and then loaded it in the popup, but I don't know how to properly design the next steps.

I'm using the wp desk InPost plugin for woo-commerce.

**I want to add 4 more steps:-**

> delivery,
>
> billing information,
>
> payment,
>
> and order summary.

I was thinking about creating delivery module from scratch, I tried:

```
WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping(WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages());
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
```

Thanks to that I can easily get to delivery options, but I don't know how to load and bind wp desk InPost plugin js functionality to one of the delivery options. My first question - it is possible to achieve this somehow?

If not, I also tried loading `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode, but then of course **ajax functionality** of **woocommerce** doesn't work.

Can I somehow after my ajax request to load that shortcode trigger **woocommerce** js to - I don't know, maybe reload and add functionality to new `HTML` content added by ajax?

Comment: @OmarTanti There are a [bunch of plugins that allow a checkout multistep](https://www.google.com/search?q=Woocommertce+checkout+multistep&oq=Woocommertce+checkout+multistep&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.11383j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)… So you should not mention one, as moderators could remove your comment thinking that you are trying to promote a plugin, which is not allowed.

Comment: @OmarTanti I am aware of plugins, but I want to do it on my own. I know how to load html content, but  woocommerce ajax functions don't work after ajax loading, probably because of binding events to previously loaded elements, not to added  by my ajax request.